# Meaning of 「くらいで」after a verb when describing an environment?

Tags: grammar, particle-くらい

What is the meaning of 「くらいで」after the verbs in these sentences?

「壁にはカレンダーが貼られている**くらいで**、ポスターなんかはいっさいない」

「その他にはミニコンポがある**くらいで**、パソコンやらテレビやらゲームやらない」

From context, I would guess it to mean something along the lines of 'even though (I have X, I don't have Y)', but I'm not fully sure, as I've never seen くらい/くらいで used like this before.